# Develop expand button in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface

I am looking to develop a dashboard in Angular JS and looking for input. I have  a reference shown in screenshot below. I highlighted the buttons that expand and show the detail view.

I want to develop something similar to that. What this button called in Angular JS? Any pointers or docs are very much appreciated. A list of all buttons or UI related things would also be very helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create and use a directive to make little bit the same thing

http://plnkr.co/edit/Itm6gdFbi6P7J1LvdXj7?p=preview

the directive

```
    // Declare the main module
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').directive('dir.showhide', function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { dswitch: "=", 
                 dshowmessage: '@' , // the message displayed in the button
                 dhidemessage :'@',  // the message displayed in the button
                 dshowmessagehover: '@' , //the message displayed on hover the button
                 dhidemessagehover :'@'},//the message displayed on hover the button
        plain : true ,
        template: '<div> <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="dswitch=true" ng-hide="dswitch" tooltip-popup-delay="500" '+
          'tooltip-placement="right" uib-tooltip="{{dshowmessagehover}}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">{{dshowmessage}}</span> </button>'+
          ' <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="dswitch=false" ng-hide="!dswitch" tooltip-popup-delay="500" tooltip-placement="right" '+
          ' uib-tooltip="{{dhidemessagehover}}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close">{{dhidemessage}}</span> </button> </div>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
        }
    }
});

myApp.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope',  function($scope) {
  $scope.showdata = false ;
  $scope.dataToShow = "I am looking to develop a dashboard in Angular JS and looking for inputs,I have a reference as shown in screen shot below ,I highlighted the buttons that expand and show the detail view,I want to develop something similar to that,what this button called in ANGULAR JS?any pointers or docs are very much appreciated .A list of all buttons or UI related things would be very helpful";

   $scope.showdata2 = false ;
  $scope.dataToShow2 = "I am looking to develop a dashboard in Angular JS and looking for inputs,I have a reference as shown in screen shot below ,I highlighted the buttons that expand and show the detail view,I want to develop something similar to that,what this button called in ANGULAR JS?any pointers or docs are very much appreciated .A list of all buttons or UI related things would be very helpful";
}]);
```

And the html code :

```
     <dir.showhide dswitch="showdata" dshowmessage="hide"  dshowmessagehover="Hide the data" dhidemessage="show" dhidemessagehover="Show the data" ></dir.showhide>

    <div ng-hide="showdata">
      {{dataToShow}}
    </div>
```

You need of course to customiz it

Comment: @Alainlb - thanks .I want to add some text beside the button that indicates what sort of text it shows while expanding,how can I add that to this code?

Comment: i updated the code. the hover tooltip are not working in the plunler